# how to use array data member of struct in main in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

If i have a struct Emp have 2 data member no_of_emp[5]; and department_name how i use no of emp array in main i am little confuse about please help  me. may be my question are not good.

```
struct emp
{
  int no_of_emp[5];
  string department_name;
 
}
```

Comment: Something like `int main(void) { emp hoge; hoge.no_of_emp[0] = 42; }`

Comment: How to use it will depend on what you want to do.

Comment: if i want to take 40 employ data then how i implement in for loop?

Comment: You may want to use `std::vector<emp>` if `emp` means an employ data.

Comment: Please post a sample of the input text.

Comment: `for(int i=0;hoge.no_of_emp[0];i++){cin>>hoge.department_name;}` will take zero or infinite employ department names, depending on the value of `hoge.no_of_emp[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it in your main with brace initialisers:

```
std::vector<emp> employers =
{
    {
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
        "department1"
    },
    {
        {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        "department2"
    }
};
```

then you can use your list of employers, for example:

```
for (const auto& x: employers)
{
    for (const auto num: x.no_of_emp)
        cout << num << " ";

    cout << x.department_name << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here we've just used a little bit of vector concept:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct emp {
    int no_of_emp[5]; // it'll store 5 elements in each struct array
    std::string department_name;
};

int main(void) {
    std::vector<emp> e;
    emp temp; // to accept values first and then add them later together
    const int max = 40; // set the maximum employee to iterate till

    // getting the values
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        std::cout << "=== Employee " << i + 1 << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // accept 5 numbers for each
            std::cout << "No. of employees: ";
            std::cin >> temp.no_of_emp[i];
        }

        std::cout << "Department name: ";
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // to avoid skipping line

        std::getline(std::cin, temp.department_name);

        e.push_back(temp); // pushing the values containing in the initialized struct
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        std::cout << "--- Employee " << i + 1 << std::endl;

        for (const auto i : e[i].no_of_emp) // getting those 5 elements of each array
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        
        std::cout << e[i].department_name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We've taken a temporary struct `temp` to retrieve all the required values from the user and then push them back together into the vector till `max`. After that, simply we print each of the struct.

You should then get the similar output:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp && ./main

=== Employee 1              // getting values
No. of employees: 3 2 3 4 3
Department name: Something
=== Employee 2
No. of employees: 1 2 4 3 3
Department name: Else

--- Employee 1             // displaying values
3 2 3 4 3 Something        // by retrieving from arrays of struct
--- Employee 2             // using vectors (format: x x x x x department)
1 2 4 3 3 Else             // till 40 times (as per of the requirement)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
struct emp e; //declare a variable of type struct emp

e.no_of_emp[0] = 25; //set the value of the first element of no_of_emp array

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //or set all the elements in no_of_emp array
    e.no_of_emp[i] = i + 1; //prints 1
}

printf("%d ", e.no_of_emp[0]); // print the first element no_of_emp array

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //or print all the elements no_of_emp array
    printf("%d ", e.no_of_emp[i]); //prints 1 2 3 4 5
}

for (auto& i : e.no_of_emp){ //or with a range based loop
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

---

C++ provides a fixed size array container, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) you can use instead of a C style array:

```
struct emp
{
  std::array<int, 5> no_of_emp;
  string department_name;
 
};
```

The code to access and set the elements can be the same.

---

Or if you need a variable lenght array you could use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Here the setting of the elements is a bit different:

```
struct emp
{
  std::vector<int> no_of_emp;
  string department_name;
 
};
```

```
e.no_of_emp.push_back(25); //set the value of no_of_emp of the first element of the array

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //or set all the no_of_emp of the structs in the array
    e.no_of_emp.push_back(i + 1);
}
```

The access can the same as if it was a C-style array like showed in the first sample code.

Comment: @MikeCAT, my bad, fixed it.